# Angular 2 - how to dynamically inject a component via an attribute directive into the selector the attribute is on instead of afterwards

Tags: angular

I am working on a project where we are creating a type of CMS with editable component widgets. For each component that's editable, a flag from a service enables an edit button to appear next to an editable component.

I've created an attribute directive that can be added to an element selector, using the ViewContainerRef and the ComponentFactoryResolver to create an instance of the edit button component and inject it. The issue I am having is that ideally I would like the injected component to be placed inside of the selector that has the attribute directive called on it. Currently it's placing the dynamically injected component after the element the attributre directive is called on.

**edit-button.directive.ts**

```ts
import { Directive, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { EditButtonComponent } from './edit-button.component';
import { Config } from '../../portal-widgets/services/config.service';

@Directive({ selector: '[pctEditable]' })

export class EditableDirective {

constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private location: 
ViewContainerRef, public config: Config, private element: ElementRef ) {

}

ngOnInit() {

  var editMode = this.config.get('edit-mode');//Set variable based on edit-mode
  if( editMode == true ){ //check if edit mode = true in config service

    var loc = <any>(this.location);
    var myParentComponent = loc._data.componentView.component;
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(EditButtonComponent);// create component 
    factory of edit component
      let ref = this.location.createComponent(factory);// insert created component instance into element
      ref.instance.widget = myParentComponent;

     }
  }
}
```

**Edit-button.component**

```html
<!-- button to activate form dialogue box and pop-up directive with parameters-->
<button type="text" (click)="showDialog()" pButton  label="Show" class="button-edit-widget"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
<p-dialog  header="Edit Form" [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" responsive="true" [draggable]=false >
    <!-- directive for form-->
    <portal-dynamic-form [widget]="widget"></portal-dynamic-form>

</p-dialog>
```

**Usage in a component selector that would be editable**

```html
<portal-text-widget #widget widgetId="text-hb" pctEditable></portal-text-widget>
```

**I'm getting my injection formatted like this**

```html
<portal-text-widget pcteditable="" widgetid="text-hb" ng-reflect-widget-id="text-hb">...</portal-text-widget>
<portal-edit-button ng-version="4.0.1">...</portal-edit-button>
```

**But really would prefer this**

```html
<portal-text-widget pcteditable="" widgetid="text-hb" ng-reflect-widget-id="text-hb">...<portal-edit-button ng-version="4.0.1">...</portal-edit-button>
</portal-text-widget>
```

Comment: why do you want a directive to inject a dynamic component?

Comment: definitely open to different methods of achieving the same result. i think the idea was that the "editableness" of a selector could be added at the template level without adding imports for each widget type.

Comment: the editable nature can be easily achieved using a boolean variable and toggle between the `ng-template` and why to complicate?

Comment: we would prefer that the components not contain the code. There are multiple build scenarios where the edit status isn't a consideration to be included in the build

Comment: handling it in the directive complicates things and you need to write separate directives for each functionality no methods can be reused. How ever its your call

Comment: It's already working with schema and multiple selector types without the need for multiple directives as it sits. It's simply the location of the injection that I would like to target.